# Who pays for "campaign rallies," nearly 4 years out?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

A number of President Trump's recent appearances around the country have been described as "campaign rallies." ([Police use tear gas...](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/22/us/trumps-rally-in-arizona-what-you-need-to-know.html), [Trump, on Long Island,...](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/28/us/politics/trump-immigration-gang-violence-long-island.html), [Trump threatens shutdown...](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/trump-holds-campaign-style-rally-amid-large-protests-in-arizona/2017/08/22/dd7c83c0-8796-11e7-961d-2f373b3977ee_story.html)) Though, notably, the phrases "campaign-style rally" and "*de facto* campaign rally" often appear, too.

[President Trump **is** already a formal candidate for 2020](https://www.fec.gov/data/?search=P80001571) (FEC filing), and has been since January 20, 2016. This is unusually early: Barack Obama filed on April 5, 2011 to run in 2012; George W. Bush filed on May 17, 2003 to run in 2004; Bill Clinton filed on April 15, 1995 to run in 1996 ([source](http://www.weeklystandard.com/obama-reelection-announcement-historically-early/article/556810), because I couldn't parse all the FEC paperwork for those three). So it raises the question:

When a(ny) president does become a candidate who pays for the rallies? I'd have naively assumed that "the taxpayer" pays for things like Air Force 1 and secret service, but who pays for a venue and vendors?

(Just to be clear, this isn't really a Trump-specific thing, just the prevalence of his rallies had me wondering. And it seems an opportune time to ask, as he's basically maximized how long a presidential campaign can last.)

Comment: There exists a [Politics chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/agora) for those who'd like to discuss anything they like. Please confine your comments to those that attempt to improve/clarify the post to which they're attached. If I'm missing anywhere up there ^^ where you're suggesting I improve the post, please make it clearer--I'm missing that message.

Comment: Sometime in the (hopefully near) future, we might get a [comments-only lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171223/162704). Until then moderators have to clean up off topic & chatty comment chains manually. We've already had two rounds of cleanups here, and it's getting a bit tiring. Please take nitsua60's advice and take any further discussions to chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this cheatsheet.com article](https://www.cheatsheet.com/money-career/trump-rally-city-how-tax-dollars-paying-bill.html) the rally is paid out of the some 7.6 million left in the 2016 campaign funds as well as any contributions to the 2020 re-election campaign.

What taxpayers absorb is:

1. Costs of local police and emergency services.
2. Costs of Street closures, traffic control and loss of business income (although it's unclear if a business just absorbs the cost of lost business or if then can seek some compensation from the city).
3. Secret Service.
4. Hospitality Costs - (hotels meals transportation etc).
5. Clean-up after event.

Apparently the cost of the venue and associated expenses (printing posters for example) are paid for by the re-election campaign.

As to the costs of AF-1 (at ~$200,000/hour) the campaign pays a proportionate part of the cost as some of the expenses "For example, a significant portion of Air Force One may be occupied by personnel and equipment mandated by national-security requirements and other needs associated with the office of the President, not the campaign." from [this NPR article](http://www.npr.org/2016/07/07/485097272/fact-check-air-force-one-who-pays).